# mvc4 range validator decimal

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have

```
[Range(typeof(decimal), "75000", "300000")]
public decimal Importo { get; set; }
```

or

```
[Range(75000, 300000)]
public decimal Importo { get; set; }
```

for a field on db: `decimal(10, 2)`

when my page load i get 75000,00 in the input
if i submit the form i get the error

`The field Importo must be between 75000 and 300000` (i got it localized in italian using globalize.js)

But 75000,00 must be a valid value.

I read to use a regexp. Any hope to use only range attribute?

Comment: solved adding 
[code]

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
        range: function (value, element, param) {
            //Use the Globalization plugin to parse the value        
            var val = Globalize.parseFloat(value);
            return this.optional(element) || (
              val >= param[0] && val <= param[1]);
          }
    });
</script>

[/code]

Answer (score 1):

try to add this

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$",ErrorMessage = "Price must can't have more than 2decimal places")]
```

this line can accept 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at this post.
http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2009/07/09/191.aspx

Comment: As described in this post, range validator doesn't work with decimals, so do it double or use regex.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx